# Dynamics CRM Error : The object cannot be updated because it is read-only when closing a Phone Call

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

[image]

User closes an active/open phone call and gets the error on the image.

[image]

Comment: is this solved?

Comment: It is somewhat more of a user error.  The user closes the appointment before the record is saved.

Answer (score 1):

The error message: `Cannot Update Closed or Cancelled Activity` is expected when some script or code piece trying to update the activity (phonecall, task, etc) but the record is marked already as completed/closed/cancelled status.

1. Check if any javascript is triggered on onSave, onChange, onLoad events
2. Check if any custom action, plugin, Workflow triggers

From the screenshot the record has unsaved changes and showing still "open" in bottom right/left corners. Quite not sure if any other pre-update plugins triggering or some other operation trying to update another activity record (which is different from this current record).